# Python boolean variable not updating within a loop

Tags: python, recursion, scope, boolean

I have two pieces of python code that I expect to give me the same result but that is not happening. I wrote the following routine for a fill type question on leetcode and got the wrong answer

```
def processIsland(self, grid: List[List[int]], proc: List[List[int]], i: int, j: int) -> bool:
    n = len(grid)
    m = len(grid[0])
    proc[i][j] = 1
    trav = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
    val = True
    for k in range(4):
        ip = i+trav[k]
        jp = j+trav[k+1]
        if 0 <= ip < n and 0 <= jp < m:
            if grid[ip][jp] == 0 and proc[ip][jp] == 0:
                val = val and self.processIsland(grid, proc, ip, jp)         
    if i == 0 or i == n-1 or j == 0 or j == m-1:
        return False
    return val
```

However when I changed it store the boolean values returned by the recursive call to the function in separate variables and take the AND at the end, my solution was accepted.

```
def processIsland(self, grid: List[List[int]], proc: List[List[int]], i: int, j: int) -> bool:
    n = len(grid)
    m = len(grid[0])
    proc[i][j] = 1
    trav = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
    val = [True, True, True, True]
    for k in range(4):
        ip = i+trav[k]
        jp = j+trav[k+1]
        if 0 <= ip < n and 0 <= jp < m:
            if grid[ip][jp] == 0 and proc[ip][jp] == 0:
                val[k] = self.processIsland(grid, proc, ip, jp)         
    if i == 0 or i == n-1 or j == 0 or j == m-1:
        return False
    val = val[0] and val[1] and val[2] and val[3]
    return val
```

I am quite perplexed as I thought that they should have identical behavior. I am new to Python so I don't know if I'm missing anything obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what that function is supposed to calculate, but note that `and` is lazy, i.e. the 'right' expression is only evaluated if the 'left' expression is not already false. In your case this means that

```
val = val and self.processIsland(grid, proc, ip, jp)
```

will only execute the recursive call if `val` is not already `False` from an earlier iteration. And since those recursive calls have side-effect (e.g. they modify `grid` and `proc`) that might be a problem.

The second version, on the other hand, always executes all four recursive calls. If you want to make that a bit prettier, you can just `return all(val)` though, instead of combining them with `and` in the previous line.

Comment: Oh you are right! I just changed the order to `val = self.processIsland(grid, proc, ip, jp) and val` and the code works.

Comment: As a side note, I realized that if `and` is lazy, I don't need to nest my two `if` conditions.

Comment: @Seven That's right, and you might also shorten it to `grid[ip][jp] == proc[ip][jp] == 0`.

Comment: In fact, you might shorten the whole last block to `return 0 < i < n-1 and 0 < j < m-1 and all(vals)`

Answer (score 1):

Understand the logical operators.

For **logical** **AND**:  If the first operator is True then only it checks next operator
Ex.

```
    def hello():
        print("Hello")

    def world():
        print("World")

    a = True
    b = False

    c = a and hello()
    c = b and world()

    Output: Hello
    Explanation:
             a is true therefore hello() function is executed.
             b is false therefore world() function is not executed.
```

Therefore your code does not makes recursive calls when **val** is **False** in first case.